# Resize Image without cropping

Tags: php, plugin-development

Currently I’m working on a WordPress plugin and as part of it users can upload Images. What I want to do is that these uploaded images of any size will be resized to 100px by 100px without cropping.

Here’s the part of the code where the resizing is done. It works but, but not without cropping. I hope someone can help getting this work without cropping the images.

It would be best if this would be possible by using the WordPress own functions only.

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( $avatar_full_path );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) ) {
    $resized = $editor->resize( 100, 100, true );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized ) ) {
        $dest_file = $editor->generate_filename();
        $saved = $editor->save( $dest_file );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $saved ) )
            $local_avatars[$size] = str_replace( $upload_path['basedir'], $upload_path['baseurl'], $dest_file );
    }
}
```

Comment: I should note that you check for errors, but if an error is returned, how do you know what it was? You're not displaying or logging the error message anywhere so that you can see what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to ignore the original image ratio. The simplest way would be using `add_image_size()` setting $crop to false.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

I found an Example in the wordpress documentation.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/image_resize_dimensions

```
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'custom_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );
function custom_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ){

// Change this to a conditional that decides whether you 
// want to override the defaults for this image or not.
if( false )
    return $payload;

if ( $crop ) {
    // crop the largest possible portion of the original image that we can size to $dest_w x $dest_h
    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $new_w = min($dest_w, $orig_w);
    $new_h = min($dest_h, $orig_h);

    if ( !$new_w ) {
        $new_w = intval($new_h * $aspect_ratio);
    }

    if ( !$new_h ) {
        $new_h = intval($new_w / $aspect_ratio);
    }

    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = 0; // [[ formerly ]] ==> floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
} else {
    // don't crop, just resize using $dest_w x $dest_h as a maximum bounding box
    $crop_w = $orig_w;
    $crop_h = $orig_h;

    $s_x = 0;
    $s_y = 0;

    list( $new_w, $new_h ) = wp_constrain_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h );
}

// if the resulting image would be the same size or larger we don't want to resize it
if ( $new_w >= $orig_w && $new_h >= $orig_h )
    return false;

// the return array matches the parameters to imagecopyresampled()
// int dst_x, int dst_y, int src_x, int src_y, int dst_w, int dst_h, int src_w, int src_h
return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );

}
```

This is not what you need at the moment, but you can easily alter this example by removing what is used to maintain image ratio.

Seeing the example above you will probably need to alter the `$new_w` and `$new_h`. It could already be enough to enter a hardcoded 100 for both. Here the changed last row.

```
return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, 100, 100, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: actually i want to ignore the image ratio. every image that i upload should be resized to 100x100px regardless of the original image´s width and height. it should be resized the same way as if it can be done with the CSS width and height properties

Comment: @Loki that comment implies you're understanding of how the image size system works isn't quite up to scratch

Comment: I've checked google for your issue and didn't find any solution. It's quite a special issue as you want to ignore a good practice issue. Without checking the issue deeper I think that you will have to write a custom image resizing function. Easiest will probably be to copy the original wordpress function and altering the parts that are used to make sure that the ratio is kept. Yet I think it's better not to ignore the image ratio.

Comment: as this is getting more complicated then i thought i decided to keep the resize function as it is and changed the $crop parameter to false and resize the image using CSS. anyway thanks for the many helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an image to WordPress, the following happens:

- The file is checked and moved into the appropriate location in the uploads folder
- A post is created of type 'attachment'
- This post is filled with metadata from the uploaded file
- For each image size defined, a copy of the original image is created according to what that image size specifies
- Any code that references that image, does so using the attachment post ID, not the URL

By default, you will get:

- The original image file
- A 'Large' image
- A 'Medium' image
- A 'Thumbnail' image

So your question does not make any sense in those terms. You have an XY problem, and you're trying to figure out a solution to your solution.

Instead of trying to resize the image to 100x100, and arriving at a completely brand new problem, you should have asked what the solution to the original problem was:

**"How do I display an attachment at 100x100 without cropping?"**

The answer lies in the image system.

When dealing with an image attachment, the APIs to grab the original image take a size parameter, e.g.:

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium');
```

What if you could specify your own size? The API lets you pass in an array like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( array( 100,100 ) );
```

But this doesn't give you a 100x100 image, it gives you the closest matching size that already exists, with height and width parameters of 100. it won't go back and resize everything for you.

Instead, if we add a new image size, and specify that it doesn't use cropping, like this:

```
// add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );
add_image_size( 'Lokis100x100', 100, 100, false );
```

Then do this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'Lokis100x100' );
```

You should get what you wanted. But there is one important thing to note. WordPress does its resizing on upload. You will need to regenerate those images or re-upload the image for it to work on those already on the site. There are numerous plugins such as regen thumbnails that will do this.

The 'Lokis100x100' image size I defined above will not crop the image. This means if I upload a 200x100 image, I will get a 100x50 image, downsized to fit into the specified dimensions. If crop was set to true, I would get a 100x100 image with the top and bottom cropped.

If somehow you are uploading images and storing their URLs, this is the wrong way to do things, and you should ask a question about this. I would recommend asking:

"When I upload an image file, I'm storing its URL. How do I handle this as an attachment post ID instead?"

### As for `wp_get_image_editor`

Your code checks if the functions returned an error, but then makes no attempt to handle that scenario

For example:

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( $avatar_full_path );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) ) {
    ...
}
```

What happens if `is_wp_error` is `true`? Nothing. The `$editor` object would be a WP_Error object not an image editor, and it would contain a message telling you what went wrong, but because you're not printing that message out, you don't know what it says. These messages can be very clear about what went wrong, such as the file you specified doesn't exist, or can't be read, or the file couldn't be saved