# How to resize Wordpress images on upload to specific height and width without cropping it

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, core

I need to make Wordpress resize automatically images on upload to fit a particular width and height. (say 300px by 400px)

I know the add_image_size() function but it doesn't seems to fit my needs. 
The image is either resized but it **keeps his ratio** or it is resized to the desired width and height but **cropped**!
**These** are not what i'm looking for.

I need the image to be "contained" into a 300x400 rectangle like the css property "background-size: contain" with eventually blank margins on borders if the image has another ratio.

Any idea please ? :)

Comment: I think this topic can help to solve my problem but i cant figure how to achieve it
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151432/resize-image-without-cropping

Answer (score 1):

WordPress's image resizing does not artwork your image onto a canvas, it just resizes mages to fit, cropping if you tell it to.

```
add_image_size('contained-image', 300, 400);
```

*will* get you the image size you want, but not letterboxed.

Images will be resized to fit tightly within a 300x400 rectangle.  However they won't be padded out to 300x400 with a border saved as part of the image.

You ought to be able to achieve that in your CSS with something like

```
img.size-contained-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Although IE & older browsers won't support this, there are polyfills.

If you're calling the images into your theme, then you could wrap them in a div and use CSS to get your result.

It's also possible to hook into WP's resizing and do your own thing.  Watermarking plugins do this, for example.